# Advice on using DRAMSimm2 or other DRAM simulation tools

Tags: reference-request, computer-architecture, memory-hardware

As part of my PhD research I am currently building a simulation of a 256 core NoC and really want to model its interaction with the memory system.

My supervisor has suggested using the University of Maryland's DRAMSim2 tools, but it looks like work on that stopped a couple of years ago and the tool is not complete, while version 1 (even older) is complete but is not in a library form. I want to try to avoid reinventing the wheel by porting this to a library if at all possible.

I was wondering if any fellow researchers had been using DRAMSim2 effectively and/or if they have discovered good replacements?

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: I'm afraid it looks to me like this question is outside of our site's scope.  (Any community votes?)  Questions about specific software products/tools are off-topic here.  Similarly, requests for recommendations of software packages are off-topic here.  See our [help/on-topic].